# Whats the template of my homepage?

Tags: templates

So i'm new at wordpress, I want to add some php code in my home page, but I don't understand why neither page.php or front-page.php seems to act as a template to my homepage

I tried to copy front-page.php and I put

```
/**
 * Template Name: homepagetemplate
**/
```

edited the html and add some super-big Text to see if it works....
Then set the template in wordpress and no big text I see.

Tried the same with page.php, but nothing seems to work, I even tried editing page.php and front-page.php directly and I see nothing

If I do the same with a page that is not my homepage it works if i edit page.php, but not for my homepage

Comment: try creating `home.php` instead. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Themes authors have different approaches and organize their files differently.

The fastest way to know which theme files were used to generate the current page is to use the plugin [What the File](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/), it adds a small section in the admin toolbar.

[image: What the File - Preview]

Comment: Its says its using archive-product.php If I click i cant edit, and if I browse for the file I cant find it, Im ussing twentyseventeen theme

Comment: This file is located in the WooCommerce plugin, you can override it like [this](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-override-woocommerce-template-files/).

Answer (score 0):

Meet your best friend: the [WordPress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

[image: https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png]

Normally, the `index.php` acts as a homepage, more rarely `home.php`, however every template can have its own way of creating it.

You 
You could, for example create a Page, then `From Settings -> Reading`, using it as a `Static FrontPage`.
You could also, reate a `php` file in your template and add at the top

```
/**
 * Template Name: homepagetemplate
**/
```

so that you can assign it to any `post type` that allows a custom Template, from the Attributes metabox (eg. Pages, but Custom Templates are now [allowed for all post types](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/), since WP v.4.7).

It all depends what you need and how you intend to structure your website, or if a custom template should be re-used for other contents too.